# Should the ad banner displayed as soon as I put the codes?

Tags: android, admob, ads, banner-ads

I Applied all steps given to me by Admob to enable ads on my android app , 
but I didn't really register (or give full information) in Adsense ,

so , when I run my app with (Test Banner Id ) then the ads are displayed.
but when I run my app with (Banner Id that given to me by admob) then the ads are not displayed .

is that normal ?? 
or I have problem ?

Comment: upload logs in your question. they will tell you reason of not displaying advertisements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ads are not displaying after publishing final application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45013329/ads-are-not-displaying-after-publishing-final-application)

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether your real admob working or not by adding your device as test device(By default all emulators are considered as test device).

**Add your test device**

1. Load your ads-integrated app and make an ad request.
2. Check the logcat output for a message that looks like this:

   I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("33BE2250B43518CCDA7DE426D04EE232")
   to get test ads on this device.

   Copy your test device ID to your clipboard.
3. Modify your code to call AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice() with your test device ID. This method can be called multiple times for multiple devices.

   AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
   .addTestDevice("33BE2250B43518CCDA7DE426D04EE232")
   .build();

If ads are visible on your test device with real id then no problem otherwise you have to check.

**Note: Be sure to remove the code that sets these test devices before you release your app.**

Comment: when I used the emulator ,then the all banners where displayed (I used banner id that obtained from Admob) .
I didn't do the steps you told us about, Is that mean that is no problem?

Comment: the real banner id just displayed in emulator , in real device showed nothing.

Comment: Did you follow the above steps for real device?