# Unity 3d Admob shows only test ads

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

I have been trying since 2 days to figure out why on earth is admob just showing the TestAds! When i use testId it show test ads. When i use my admob banner id it becomes blank(no ads shown) 
Below ive attached my admob banner code.

```js
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

public class AdmobScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public string BannerId;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        //Request Ads
        RequestBanner();

    }

    private void RequestBanner()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        string adUnitId = "unused";
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
  string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
#elif UNITY_IPHONE
   string adUnitId = "INSERT_IOS_BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE";
#else
   string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
#endif

        // Create a 320x50 banner at the bottom of the screen.
        BannerView bannerView = new BannerView(adUnitId, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Bottom);
        // Create an empty ad request.
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        // Load the banner with the request.
        bannerView.LoadAd(request);
    }
}
```

I tried to research on why it aint working but unfortunately there are very less unity related admob solutions available on the internet.

Google Mobile Ads Plugin v3.13.1
Unity 2017.4.0f1

Please help me out! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

public class AdmobScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    private string BannerId;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake()
    {
        //Request Ads
        RequestBanner();

    }

    private void RequestBanner()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        string adUnitId = "unused";
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
        string adUnitId = "You UNIT-ID HERE";
#elif UNITY_IPHONE
            string adUnitId = "INSERT_IOS_BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE";
#else
            string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
#endif

        // Create a 320x50 banner at the bottom of the screen.
        BannerView bannerView = new BannerView(adUnitId, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Bottom);
        // Create an empty ad request.
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        // Load the banner with the request.
        bannerView.LoadAd(request);
    }
}
```

Make sure you UNIT-ID is correct. Do not put your APP-ID instead of UNIT-ID.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "publish your application" :)

Comment: Alright see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45013329/ads-are-not-displaying-after-publishing-final-application

Comment: You dont have to publish your game to android store first i guess. I thought after 2017 you have to publish your app before you get real ads. Good luck.

Comment: i even tried with the bannerId of already published app. but even that doesnt work. Only test ads work :(

Comment: make bannerId private and put ur unityID to string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; here and try calling RequestBanner in Awake function

Comment: please share me the code of what you are trying to explain

Comment: private string BannerId;

void Awake()
{
RequestBanner();
}

#elif UNITY_ANDROID
  string adUnitId = "//put your UNITY-ID here";

And Make sure you dont put your APP-ID instead of UNIT-ID most people do this mistake.

Comment: can you edit the script and post it as answer? so i can accept it?

Comment: it only works on testID "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111
"

Comment: Damn sorry couldnt help ):

Comment: do you know any script that works? i mean i just wanna show banner ads....

Comment: Your script works fine! Something is wrong with your ADMOB or Unit-ID.

Comment: im stuck. ;-; dude

Comment: i tried with different account also but doesnt work.

Comment: I dont really know bro!

Answer (score 0):

I was running into a similar problem, and it turns out that AdMob won't serve ads unless you have payment information set up. So make sure that is set up.

Also, when switching from using the test ads to actual ads, you need to make sure to change your app ID as well as your unit ID. It looks like you may only be changing your unit ID.

Somewhere else in your project you should have something like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;


public class AdInitializer : MonoBehaviour {

    public void Start()
    {
        #if UNITY_ANDROID
        string appId = "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX~XXXXXXXXXX";
        #elif UNITY_IPHONE
        string appId = "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX~XXXXXXXXXX";
        #else
        string appId = "unexpected_platform";
        #endif

        // Initialize the Google Mobile Ads SDK.
        MobileAds.Initialize(appId);
        Debug.Log ("Initializing ads for app ID " + appId);
    }
}
```

Make sure this is using your app IDs and not the test app IDs.